# How to convert TEXT data to DATE TIME in SQLITE in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I am new to android. I am using a database to store my data. I also store date as TEXT in database. format of date is as follow...
"Mon, 20 Oct 2010 12:30:00"
So i stored them in TEXT datatype not in DateTime. Now i want to display them in following format
"Mon, 20 Oct 2010"   The main thing is that i want to ORDER them in DESC. I write a query for this but it dose not work. It there is some alternative for this???? i also read about "strftime()" function of SQLITE but i did not know how to use it for this.

My Query is:

"Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("Select * from List ORDER BY to_date(substr(date,6,20), 'DD-MM-YYYYTHH24:MI:SS') DESC",null);"

Please Help me... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i store date as text format and then after retrieve i sort date by sending my text(date) value to the constructor of Date class. And the using that object i sort them and adjust items related to that dated in proper location by Insertion Sort logic. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to store your DateTime values as `INTEGER` using `Date.getTime()` (milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT). So you can use `ASC` and `DESC` operators without conversions which will require less resources.

Comment: So in such a case i have to store my date in 2 columns. It is right?

Comment: Why do you need 2 columns? 1 will be enough.

Comment: But i am storing whole date as TEXT because need this whole date for display to user, but in such a case it must be sorted in DESC... For 1 column for whole date and 1 for TIME as INTEGER?????

Comment: No. Date.getTime() converts both date and time to into single integer value. Same way you can convert it back to Date after reading from database and format it as needed.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Can you please send me a example or a useful link?

Comment: Date.getTime() is a java funtion? or a sqlite function?

Comment: java.util.Date. However I believe SQL type has similar functionality.

Comment: It is a java function that converts java.util.Date to long that can be stored as INTEGER in SQLite database.